# Magento reindexing issue - General error: 1005 Can't create table (errno: 121)

Tags: mysql, magento

I am unable to reindex Product Flat Data on production server and I am using the following command.

```
nohup php -f indexer.php -- --reindex catalog_product_flat &
```

The error message is:

```
Next exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table 'database_name.catalog_product_flat_2' (errno: 121)' in /home/corecolu/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:234
Stack trace:
#0 /home/corecolu/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home/corecolu/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/corecolu/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /home/corecolu/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('CREATE TABLE `c...', Array)
#4 /home/corecolu/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(389): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('CREATE TABLE `c...', Array)
#5 /home/corecolu/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(2018): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('CREATE TABLE `c...')
#6 /home/corecolu/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Flat/Indexer.php(702): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->createTable(Object(Varien_Db_Ddl_Table))
#7 /home/corecolu/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Flat/Indexer.php(1390): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Flat_Indexer->prepareFlatTable(2)
#8 /home/corecolu/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Flat/Indexer.php(296): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Flat_Indexer->reindexAll()
#9 /home/corecolu/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Indexer/Flat.php(336): Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Flat_Indexer->reindexAll()
#10 /home/corecolu/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(207): Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Indexer_Flat->reindexAll()
#11 /home/corecolu/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(253): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#12 /home/corecolu/public_html/shell/indexer.php(158): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#13 /home/corecolu/public_html/shell/indexer.php(198): Mage_Shell_Compiler->run()
#14 {main}
```

I tried truncating and dropping the tables(the 4 flat tables) and they did no work. The indexing process can create and index two flat tables successfully(_flat_1 and _flat_3) and it always gets stuck on `catalog_product_flat_2`. However if I get the same database into development server and then truncate or drop the flat tables, the reindexing works fine.

I think that this is the related error from innodb status:

```
------------------------
LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
------------------------
141214 20:48:16 Error in foreign key constraint creation for table `database_name`.`catalog_product_flat_2`.
A foreign key constraint of name `database_name`.`FK_CAT_PRD_FLAT_2_ENTT_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID`
already exists. (Note that internally InnoDB adds 'databasename'
in front of the user-defined constraint name.)
Note that InnoDB's FOREIGN KEY system tables store
constraint names as case-insensitive, with the
MySQL standard latin1_swedish_ci collation. If you
create tables or databases whose names differ only in
the character case, then collisions in constraint
names can occur. Workaround: name your constraints
explicitly with unique names.
```

I appreciate any help on this issue.

Answer (score 1):

A few weeks ago I had the same problem - without any reason all tables have been changed to MyISAM and after that I got the same error as you. Magento strictly requires InnoDB (foreign keys and transactions). After I changed the engine for all tables the problem was solved.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/227/convert_database_to_innodb

Comment: Our tables did not get changed to MyISAM

Answer (score 0):

you need to check in your schema FK_CAT_PRD_FLAT_2_ENTT_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID id this key has been already defined.
Also check your core files or modules that might have customized catalog flat product indexing.Probably there is some modification in indexing code thats resulting in similar key constraint creation twice.

Comment: Could you please elaborate how I can check if that is already defined? Do you mean the table table_constraints? If so, it is not there. This site does not have any modules or code that could customize the indexing.

Comment: Either above stated constraint is already in place before you start indexing or when indexing starts its created twice so on second time this will fail.Extract schema of your data dabse with foreign key constraints and check

Comment: I exported the database; the flat 1 table constraint and flat 3 table constraint exist in the schema like how they should be. The flat 2 constraint is not there. I read on another place where another same mysql and non-magento issue was resolved by exporting and importing database into a new database name. That's an another way to try.

Comment: Yes probably some issue with your data base table.So if you create a new data base from existing data base by export and then import that might sort this.